# JmsListener picks up the first message but ignores subsequent messages until a few minutes later

Tags: java, jms, azureservicebus, spring-jms, azure-servicebus-topics

So I can send a first message, it get consumed just fine. Then I immediately send another message but it doesn't get picked up by listener. I wait around 4 mins then send another message which gets picked up by the listener. Although the second message gets lost and never sent.

I'm sending messages manually through the azure service bus explorer.

Here is my config and listener

Config:

```
    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> topicContainerFactory(
        ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory,
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);
        factory.setReceiveTimeout(receiveTimeout);
        factory.setSubscriptionDurable(Boolean.TRUE);
        factory.setSessionTransacted(Boolean.TRUE);
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);

        configurer.configure(factory, jmsConnectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory(@Value("${spring.application.name}") final String clientId) {
        String connection = String.format(AMQP_CONNECTION_STRING_TEMPLATE, namespace + connectionPostfix, idleTimeout);
        JmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory = new JmsConnectionFactory(connection);
        jmsConnectionFactory.setUsername(username);
        jmsConnectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        jmsConnectionFactory.setClientID(clientId);

        return new CachingConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);
    }
```

Listener:

```
@JmsListener(
        destination = "${azure.topicName}",
        subscription = "${azure.subscriptionName}",
        containerFactory = "topicContainerFactory")
    public void onMessage(Message message) throws JMSException, HmcTopicEventProcessingException {
        log.info("message received");
}
```

Basically I need all messages to be consumed by the listener so I'm not sure why some are getting lost.

Comment: Hi, were you able to fix the issue? I have similar problem also with JmsListener